# highcharts breaking when I input seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

I have a series of data which contain the full date all the way down to the second.

The problem is that the highchart tooltips stop working when I have seconds in the date, only the very first and the very last tooltip work in this case.

If I remove the seconds then everything works fine, I have tried most of the charts but I can't seem to find a solution.

Sample:

```
data: [
    [Date.UTC(2014,10,25,16,50,57),2.3000], 
    [Date.UTC(2014,10,25,16,50,38),2.0000],
    [Date.UTC(2014,10,25,16,50,19),2.0000],
    [Date.UTC(2014,10,25,16,50,00),2.3000]
    ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0bzm92pd/

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved, the time data needs to be in ascending order, I was putting it in descending.